# Using react refs to focus on sibling element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I am trying to create a react form that uses refs. What I need is when the user inputs a value in one input field. it should automatically focus on the next sibling element i.e. second input element and so on until the end of the input fields are reached and the form's value should get automatically gets saved into the state.

I am quite new to using react refs. I tried developing a basic working but is stuck on error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nextSibling' of undefined
Todo._handleKeyPress
  22 |    
  23 |    e.preventDefault();
  24 | 
> 25 |    let next = this.refs[field.name].nextSibling;
     | ^  26 |    if (next && next.tagName === "INPUT") {
  27 |      this.refs[field.name].nextSibling.focus();
  28 |    }




import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./style.css";

class Todo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); // create a ref to store the textInput DOM element

    this.state= {

    }


    this.textInput1 = React.createRef();
    this.textInput2 = React.createRef();
    this.textInput3 = React.createRef();
  }

  _handleKeyPress = (e, field) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let next = this.refs[field.name].nextSibling;
    if (next && next.tagName === "INPUT") {
      this.refs[field.name].nextSibling.focus();
    }
  };


submitForm = () => {

}


  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <form onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
          <input
            type="number"
            name={this.textInput1}
            maxLength="1"
            ref={this.textInput1}
            onKeyPress={e => this._handleKeyPress(e, this.textInput1)}
          />
          <input
            type="number"
            name={this.textInput2}
            maxLength="1"
            ref={this.textInput3}
            onKeyPress={e => this._handleKeyPress(e, this.textInput2)}
          />
          <input
            type="number"
            name={this.textInput3}
            maxLength="1"
            ref={this.textInput3}
            onKeyPress={e => this._handleKeyPress(e, this.textInput3)}
          />

          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Todo />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I have included the demo code in the link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6gsfxd. ANy kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: What is `this.refs`? You are getting an error because you are using something that you didn't declared.

Comment: @JohnnyZabala this.refs is the input refs defined in the constructor.

Comment: No, React doesn't automatically creates a `this.refs` attribute when you declare a ref. You use the same refs you declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument `field` is already a reference to the input element, you don't need to call it with `this.refs`.

I have made few changes in `_handleKeyPress` method.

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./style.css";

class Todo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); // create a ref to store the textInput DOM element

    this.state= {

    }


    this.textInput1 = React.createRef();
    this.textInput2 = React.createRef();
    this.textInput3 = React.createRef();
  }

  _handleKeyPress = (e, field) => {

    let next = field.current.nextSibling;
    field.current.nextSibling.focus();
  };


submitForm = () => {

}


  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <form onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
          <input
            type="number"
            name={this.textInput1}
            maxLength="1"
            ref={this.textInput1}
            onKeyUp={e => this._handleKeyPress(e, this.textInput1)}
          />
          <input
            type="number"
            name={this.textInput2}
            maxLength="1"
            ref={this.textInput2}
            onKeyUp={e => this._handleKeyPress(e, this.textInput2)}
          />
          <input
            type="number"
            name={this.textInput3}
            maxLength="1"
            ref={this.textInput3}
            onKeyUp={e => this._handleKeyPress(e, this.textInput3)}
          />

          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Todo />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fegfq3?file=index.js

Comment: It's focusing on the inputs, but I am unable to see the input values?

Comment: Remove the `e.preventDefault();` from the method

Comment: Thanks it's working. Just one more thing. How can I access the values entered? inside _handleKeyPress() function `console.log(this.input.current.value)`. Will this work?

Comment: Use this `console.log(field.current.value)`

Comment: Also I will recommend to use 'onKeyUp' instead of `onKeyPress`. onKeyPress has issue when you enter in last input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207470/discussion-between-sohail-and-bubble-cord).

Answer (score -1):

```
const InputForm = () => {
  const focusChangeHandler = (e) => {
  const { value, name } = e.target;
  const [fieldName, fieldIndex] = name.split("-");
  if (parseInt(fieldIndex) < 4) {
    const nextfield = document.querySelector(
      `input[name=field-${parseInt(fieldIndex) + 1}]`
    );
    // If found, focus the next field
    if (nextfield !== null) {
      nextfield.focus();
    }
  }
};

return (
  <form>
    <input
      name="field-1"
      onChange={focusChangeHandler}
      type="text"
      maxLength="1"
    />
    <input
      name="field-2"
      onChange={focusChangeHandler}
      type="text"
      maxLength="1"
    />
    <input
      name="field-3"
      onChange={focusChangeHandler}
      type="text"
      maxLength="1"
    />
    <input
      name="field-4"
      onChange={focusChangeHandler}
      type="text"
      maxLength="1"
    />
  </form>
);
```

};

export default InputForm;